# I can't save images to folder the app directory directly

Tags: java, android, file

I have a method that calls the camera and save the image to the folder in the application directory

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File mFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/confirmation");
        File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.jpg");
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

Method `context.getFilesDir()` returns: `"/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files"`

`confirmation` is the folder in which i want to save the image

But it doesn't work, the file is not saved, what did I do wrong?

Comment: ` mFolder.mkdir();` Checkk the return value for false. It might not have created the directory. Then display a Toast and do not continue but return. Did you check if the directory is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But... the MediaStore will not save to `getFilesDir()`.

Try `getExternalFilesDir()` instead.

Ohhh you are not saving to the MediaStore. But... the Camera app cannot store to your apps private direction too so use getExternalFilesDir().

After that you will have a FileUriExposedException.

After that you will use a FileProvider.

And after that you can use getFilesDir() again.